# How do Arab sheikhs cope with new FACTA requirements?

Tags: bank-account, common-reporting-standard

I have noticed that FACTA, especially in Commonwealth countries, like the UK, has began to require elaborate and extensive information disclosures to open or maintain any bank account. For example, banks in the UK apparently require their account holders to declare all of their "assets" both real and financial. So, if we imagine an arab sheikh, they would require the sheikh to enumerate all of his bank accounts all over the world, all of his yachts, airplanes, houses, factories, mutual funds, etc, etc, etc, wherever in the world they might be. This is for ANY bank account, even an account with $1,000 in it.

So, how do arab sheikhs deal with this requirement? Is there some way for them to do banking in London without making these extensive declarations?

Comment: Are you asking about FATCA? FACTA != FATCA

Comment: Why Arab sheiks? Why do we think they do it differently from Russian or American billionaires?

Comment: @DJClayworth You right, pretty much anybody with a complex net worth would have a problem.

Comment: "banks in the UK apparently require their account holders to declare all of their "assets" both real and financial" CITATION NEEDED

Answer (score 2):

> So, how do arab sheikhs deal with this requirement? Is there some way for them to do banking in London without making these extensive declarations?

I don't know if the banks really require to enumerate *all* the holdings, and if so - why. I don't believe FATCA has such a requirement (if that's what you're referring to).

The US FATCA requires banks to identify their American customers and report information about them to the US law enforcement agencies (IRS/FinCEN etc).

In any case, rich folks don't own all their things outright. They have holding companies and subsidiaries for that. So your average Arab sheikh would own 2-3 different companies which would own all of these riches, and an army of accountants and lawyers to keep track of all that. I don't imagine them going into the main street bank branch in London to fill forms themselves, anyway. They've got people to do that.

---

[FACTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_and_Accurate_Credit_Transactions_Act) and [FATCA](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/corporations/foreign-account-tax-compliance-act-fatca) are different things, from your question it seems that you're asking about FATCA.

Comment: I am not talking about the US. The question is specifically about Commonwealth countries only. The compliance agents in Commonwealth banks call it a "Source of Wealth" declaration (https://complyadvantage.com/insights/what-is-source-of-funds-source-wealth/) and it basically requires you to not only list your entire wealth, but where all the money came from. So, for example, if you have a yacht, you have to declare the yacht, then you have to explain where the money came from to buy the yacht, even if you bought the yacht 20 years ago.

Comment: @FiveBagger what is that "FACTA" that you were referring to then? I'm only familiar with a US law in that name (and another US law named FATCA, which is more relevant to the context of your question)